# Filter array of objects where one object's array has at least one match with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I apologize in advance, couldn't come up with a better example for data.

So I have the array `things`, which currently just consists of objects that contain an `id` property and an array which just contains random things/words I could suddenly come up with, and `other_things`, with with some random words from `things` array.

```js
let things=[
  {
    id: 1,
    names: ['car','door','chair']
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    names: ['cat','dog','door']
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    names: ['phone','mouse','cat']
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    names: ['building','desk','pen']
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    names: ['road','date','number']
  }
];

let other_things=['car','door','pen'];
```

What I'd like to achieve is to filter array `things`, and only get those objects/elements, where the `names` array contains at least one element from the `other_things` array.

In this example, only `things[2]` and `things[4]` have no matches with any words from `other_things`, so we don't need them.

I have already tried many things, like combining ES6 methods, like `filter`, `every` or `map`, tried using nested `for` loops, but nothing has worked out for me unfortunately.

Comment: `const other = { car: true, door: true, pen: true }; /* can be generated from array */ let result = things.filter(({ names }) => names.some(e => other[e] ?? false ));` If your items aren't strings, use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead, or just do something cheap like `includes` or `indexOf` on `ither_things` directly, if you only have a couple dozen or hundred items at best.

Comment: Tbh, for the structure to check, even a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) should be enough, you don't care about insertion order or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let things=[
  {
    id: 1,
    names: ['car','door','chair']
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    names: ['cat','dog','door']
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    names: ['phone','mouse','cat']
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    names: ['building','desk','pen']
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    names: ['road','date','number']
  }
];

let other_things=['car','door','pen'];

console.log(things.filter(t => t.names.filter(n => other_things.includes(n)).length > 0))
```